# Refresh a tab of an ajax page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I'm having a little problem with refreshing a tab and not a whole page in Ajax.
This tab concerns the removal of credit cards.
Once I select the credit card I want to delete and validate I use "**`window.location.reload ();`**" which allows refreshing the whole page but suddenly it sends me back to "My profile" (see photo):

Before refresh:

[image]

After refresh:

[image]

While I want it refreshes only tab "means of payment" here is my code:

```
handleCardDelete = () => {
    var numCard = $('input[name=rbCard]:checked').val();
    console.log(this.state.token);
     $.ajax({
        url: 'http://API.....,

        dataType: 'json',

        type: 'DELETE',

        headers: {
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + this.state.token
        },

        complete: function(){
            alert("carte supprimée avec succès");
            window.location.reload();
        },

    });

};
```

HTML

```
<Button animated='fade' onClick={this.handleAddCardSubmit}>
    <Button.Content visible>
        Ajouter une carte
    </Button.Content>
    <Button.Content hidden>
        <Icon name='add' />
    </Button.Content>
</Button>

<Button animated='fade' onClick={this.handleCardDelete}>
    <Button.Content visible>
        Supprimer la carte
    </Button.Content>
    <Button.Content hidden>
        <Icon name='delete' />
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

I hope I have been clear, I continue my research and I wish you a good day!

Comment: how are you loading your tabs are you using jquery UI tabs or bootstrap

Comment: I said it above. I use: window.location.reload();   It's JavaScript

Comment: :D dude i am asking about the `TABS` the one you are saying in your question "**I'm having a little problem with refreshing a tab**"

Comment: I think we do not understand!
I speak tab (tabs) in french. Tab is "My Profile", "Means of Payment", "Contact Us", "About Asaplace". All its under windows are tabs .... so I do not understand your answer: D

Comment: @ValentinLemains How does a user get from one tab to the other? Does each tab represent a new page, or are each tab dynamically generated based on user interactions via JavaScript? If they are dynamically generated, when you reload the page, then you are going back to initial state of that page, as if the user hadn't clicked on an open tab. Would it be better to simply remove the deleted data from the page using `jQuery.remove()` on the selected card?

Comment: @wlh Yes indeed the tabs are different pages each tab is a different page but imported on the same page. The problem is there, I still have not found the solution .. ^^

Answer (score 0):

There are two easy options to handle this. The issue you are seeing is that the page doesn't remember which tab was open when it is refreshed. You can either save this in `storage` or add it to the url query string, then on page load, check if a tab was saved and start there. I will include documentation for using storage as this is my preferred way.

Please note however, there are some drawbacks to this method. The tab changes will not register in the browser history, so clicking back will take you to the previous page rather than previous tab, as well as not being supported on some very early versions of browsers.

You don't have an "openTab" method in your posted code, so I will use `openTab(tab)` as a placeholder for that function in your code.

[Local Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

There are two options here, both used the same way, local storage or session storage. I'm guessing session storage would be the best option for you.

> The `localStorage` object stores the data with no expiration date. The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year.
>
> The `sessionStorage` object is equal to the `localStorage` object, except that it stores the data for only one session. The data is deleted when the user closes the specific browser tab.

```
// this will be run on page load
$(function() {
    // check if a tab was saved
    if (sessionStorage.tab) {
        // here is where you will open the tab previously saved
        openTab(sessionStorage.tab);
    }
    // if no tab saved, don't do anything, load page like normal
})

// this will be in your openTab() function
openTab(tab) {
    // this will be the new code
    // this is just saving the opened tab to local storage
    //
    // tab is just what ever identifying piece of data you need
    // to know which tab to open
    sessionStorage.tab = tab;

    // this is what you were normally doing
    .....
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tyler for your answer! She is very precise and well done. I'm going to set up the code tomorrow and I'll let you know, it should work :)

Comment: Hi Tyler. I just tested your code thank you it is very understandable except that the problem is that I do not use html but ReactJs. So for the tabs backup this happens differently. I continue my research and I keep you informed

Comment: So now we are getting somewhere! This is the first time you mentioned you are using `React`!! If you reload the browser, you are in effect resetting the entire state of your application (unless you are using something like redux).

So, how are your card elements being generated? Are you mapping over a list in your state and then rendering individual cards? If so, you need to simply update your state to remove an item from the list and React should take care of the issue. Show us more of your React Code!!!

Comment: So instead of `window.location.reload()`, you will call `this.setState({/**whatever is used to generate element**/})` either on this element or have some sort of helper function passed down via props to update state on the parent element if necessary

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer, excuse me not to have specified I am so used to working with React that I forgot. Look at this post it's my problem ...: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48807295/just-refresh-a-tab-or-not-the-page